# Fixed header with vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

How can i have a `fixed header` with a vertical `scroll-bar` for my each `column`.

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="secondary-aside"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">Title 1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">Title 2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">Title 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my css...

```
html, body, .container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%; /*keep html and body 100% */
    margin:0;
    background:#e5e5e5;
}
.container {
    display:table;
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
    border-spacing:1.5em;
}

.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.col-sm-4 {
    display:table-cell;
    background:white;
}
.header{
  background:#E5E5E5;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}

.secondary-aside{
  width:260px;
  background-color:#E1E1E1;
  height:100%;
  right:0px;
  position:fixed;
}
```

Below is my codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lqfxt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `overflow` property only applies to **`block`** and **`inline-block`** elements. In order to show the scroll bar, you'll need to change the `display` property from `table-cell` to one of the two aforementioned display properties, and then add an `overflow` property. You'll also need to set a specific width/height in this case.

In order to fix the header to the top, simply apply `position: absolute;` to the header element and give your columns a `margin-top` to equal the header height:

```
.col-sm-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 600px;
    background:white;
    overflow-y: visible;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.header{
    background:#E5E5E5;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**[Example CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sCIJc)**

Comment: Thanks Tyler... i want a fixed header inside my column.... The Title 1 is a header which should be fixed....

Comment: @theJava ahh, I see. In that case, the answer will be a little more involved, with some `absolute` and `relative` positioning, but I think there are probably lots of questions/answers about that here on SO already. Try searching something like "fixed header inside a column" or similar!